# Can't access string inside SearchTerm anonymous class

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to search a mail using subject text in java mail api(javax.mail), but I cant access the subject string inside the anonymous class like this,

```
Message[] messages = null;
final String searchText = mailParam.getSearchText();
SearchTerm serachCondition = new SearchTerm() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public boolean match(Message message) {
            try {
                if (message.getSubject().contains(searchText)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
messages = folder.search(serachCondition);
```

Over here I can't access the final string searchText inside the overridden method match. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: `MyOuterClass.this.searchText`

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: @0x1C1B the above piece of code is inside of a method in a class

Comment: @AJN Yea you're right, but [piy26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430428/piy26) already said it, it's not possible to access a local variable. So for this it must be declared as **instance variable**. Then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final. Like a nested class, a declaration of a type (such as a variable) in an anonymous class shadows any other declarations in the enclosing scope that have the same name.

```
final String searchText = mailParam.getSearchText();
```

You can rather make **searchText** as an **instance** variable instead of a **local variable** at the above line

Comment: I am trying out

Comment: I declared an instance variable and then used it in my search functionality like if (message.getSubject().contains(className.this.searchText)). Thank you very much. Thanks everyone